# Problem changing state value in react native with result of filter method

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

UPDATED POST WITH FULL CODE :

so i'm having an issue setting a state value to the result of a
filter/saying undefined evaluating dataShow.text.presentation  which is the first line where i use dataShow.something.

when "dataShow" state suppose to be an object with "text" property  which is also an object  who contain "presentation" property.

here my code :

```
import { Text, View, Content, Container, Spinner, List, Header, Body, Title } from 'native-base'
import React, {useState, useContext, useEffect} from 'react'
import { AsyncStorage, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import { ShopContext } from '../../App';

var s = require("../../styles/styles")
var l = require("../../i18n/fr")

function DetailsPage(props) {

    const {shopData,setShopData} = useContext(ShopContext)
    const {userFavList,setUserFavList} = useContext(ShopContext)

    const [isLoading,setIsLoading] = useState(true)
    const [dataShow,setDataShow] = useState([])
    const [callPicture,setCallPicture] = useState('')
    const [isOpen,setIsOpen] = useState(false)
//________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________

    useEffect(() => {

        // console.log(userFavList)
        // console.log('END OF USEFAVLIST')

        // console.log(shopData)//return an array of object 
        // console.log('END SHOPDATA')

        console.log('propsName From Search Result Page : '+ props.nameFromResultsPage) // here  i have selected name from parent page

            const selectedData = shopData.filter(item => item.name === props.nameFromResultsPage)
            console.log('selectedData : '+ selectedData)//sending [objet Objet] in console
            setDataShow(dataShow => [...dataShow, selectedData])

            console.log(dataShow)//Array [] in console
            console.log('END DATASHOW')
        
       setTimeout(() => {
           setIsLoading(false)
           
       }, 500); 
    }, [])

//________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________

        // AJOUTER AU FAVORIS
        function addToFav (){

            let checkMyFav = AsyncStorage.getItem("userFavorites")
    
            if(userFavList == null){
                userFavList= []
            } else {
                userFavList = JSON.parse(userFavList)
            }
    
            userFavList.push(dataShow);
            AsyncStorage.setItem("userFavorites",JSON.stringify(userFavList))
            // console.log('FAV: ' + JSON.stringify(userFavList))
        }

//________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________

        //VOIR LA DESCRIPTION COMPLETE OU TRONQUEE
        function voirPlus(){
            setIsOpen(!isOpen)
        }

//________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________

        //LOADING SCREEN
    if(isLoading === true){
        return(
            <Container>
                <Content contentContainerStyle={{flex:1,justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center',height:'100%'}}>
                        <Spinner color='#E64511'/>
                </Content>
            </Container>

        )
    }

    //________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________

    //PAGE DE DETAIL
    if(isLoading=== false){

    let presentationfull = dataShow.text.presentation
    let presentationslice = presentationfull.slice(0, 150)

    //________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________

    return (
        <ScrollView >
           
           {isLoading === false ?
            <List>

            <Header style={s.header_detailPage}>
                <Body>
                    <Title style={s.TxtcolorHeader_detailPage}>{dataShow.name}</Title>
                </Body>
            </Header>

            {callPicture !== undefined ? 
                <Image source={{ uri: dataShow.media.logo.big }} style={s.img_detailPage} ></Image> 
                : <Image source={{ uri: dataShow.media.logo.small }} style={s.img_detailPage} ></Image>
            }

            <View style={s.cardContainer_detailPage}>
                <Button transparent onPress={()=> addToFav()}>
                    <Icon style={{ color: dataShow !== true ? '#E64511' : 'grey', fontSize: 24 }} name='heart' />
                    <Text style={{color:'black'}}>Favoris</Text>
                </Button>

                <Button transparent style={s.retourBtn_detailPage}>
                    <Text>Retour</Text>
                </Button>

                <Text style={s.favDesc_detailPage}>{l.oclock_code}</Text>
                <Text style={s.desc_detailPage}>{dataShow.text.opening_time}</Text>
                <Text style={s.favDesc_detailPage}>{l.address_code}</Text>
                <Text>{dataShow.address}</Text>
                <Text >{dataShow.postalcode}, {dataShow.city}</Text>
                {/* <Text style={s.color_buttonLine}>{button}</Text> */}
                <Text>{l.presentation_code}</Text>
                
                <Text>
                    {isOpen === false ?
                        <View style={{ width: 290 }}>
                            <Text>{presentationslice}</Text>
                            <Button transparent style={s.retourBtn_detailPage} onPress={() => voirPlus()}>
                                <Text style={{color:'black'}}>Voir plus</Text>
                            </Button>
                        </View> :
                        <View style={{ width: 290 }}>
                            <Text>{presentationfull}</Text>
                            <Button transparent style={s.retourBtn_detailPage} onPress={() => voirPlus()}>
                                <Text style={{color:'black'}}>Voir moins</Text>
                            </Button>
                        </View>
                    }
                </Text>

                <Button style={s.buttonOrange2} onPress={() => returnOrder()}>
                    <Text style={s.color_buttonOrange}>{l.button_shops}</Text>
                </Button>

            </View>
        </List>

    : <Text></Text>
}
            
        </ScrollView>
    )}
}

export default DetailsPage
```

is it a state setting error ? or my return is executed too early ?

here is one of my object:
[image]

Comment: show your shopData

Comment: shopData is an array of object and i have it in my console

Comment: shopData is API data passed from App component  to this component with Context if its more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing basic dependencies in your `useEffect`, without them you may run its callback with staled data.

```
useEffect(() => {...}, [props.nameFromResultsPage,shopData]);
```

It should show some warnings if you using CRA with `eslint`.

Comment: no warning just an error saying my dataShow.text is undefined in component return

Comment: It not saying much, you should add more info see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)